# Adding additional fields to document before response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a request that I respond to as such:

```
function getstuff(req, res) {       
    var url = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query.u;

    Thing.findOne({url: url}, function (err, doc){    
        doc.newThings = 'some text!';
        res.json(doc);
    });
}
```

I'd like to be able to append some additional data to the document before I send it along to the client. The method I've tried above doesn't seem to be working. Is there clean way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
Thing.findOne({url: url}).lean().exec(function (err, doc){    
    doc.newThings = 'some text!';
    res.json(doc);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to update the actual document in the DB though - just add some stuff to the JSON I'm sending to the client.

Comment: @opticon how about now with `.lean()`